# What duration bonds are held by the ETF XBB

Tags: canada, etf, bond-funds

I am looking at the bond etf [XBB](https://www.google.ca/finance?q=TSE%3AXBB&ei=HrQxVbmWKob4rAHjwoBQ). This ETF mostly holds Canada govt bonds. What I don't understand is what is the duration of these bonds held by the fund?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [factsheet](http://www.blackrock.com/ca/individual/en/literature/fact-sheet/xbb-ishares-canadian-universe-bond-index-etf-fund-fact-sheet-en-ca.pdf) the average duration of the portfolio is 7.51 years.